# Fetching Jobs by one thread but executing jobs by multiple threads in parallel

Tags: java, multithreading

I am getting Jobs from a DB. I want fetching of records from DB to be single threaded. Once I have all the jobs I want them to be executed by number of threads in parallel.

Comment: What exactly is your question? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am using Spring scheduler to achieve this. But all this I am doing using a single thread.But now I am planning to make it multi threaded.

Comment: I'm sorry but your question doesn't really show your issue. But to be helpful : try to set up a `BlockingQueue` that is filled by your thread querying the DB, and a threadpool polling from the queue until it is empty.

Comment: @JeremyGrand : Thanks that what I am trying. But is there any better way than using Blocking Queue.

Answer (score 0):

As you said you're using Spring, I'd advise you to look up [their documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#scheduling-task-executor).

Then, you could have your thread querying the DB submit your jobs (wrapped in `Callable` or `Runnable`) to a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`.

Answer (score 0):

1. First fetching the records from the database to process.
2. I am grouping records with the customers.
3. I am passing processing for each customer to a thread pool.

   ```
   .....
   @Autowired
   ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor;

   @Autowired
   private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

   @Transactional
   public void processPendingPayments() {
       logger.debug("ProcessPendingPayments.processPendingPayments begins");
       logger.info("startTime::" + System.currentTimeMillis());
       List<PaymentRequestEntity> recordsPendingForPayment = getRecordsPendingForPayment();

       // Group Requests with Customers
       Map<String, List<PaymentRequestEntity>> customerPaymentRequestsMap = getPendingRecordsGroupedByCustomer(
               recordsPendingForPayment);

       // process Payment requests for customers
       for (String customerId : customerPaymentRequestsMap.keySet()) {

           CustomerPaymentRequestProcessor customerPaymentRequestProcessor = (CustomerPaymentRequestProcessor) applicationContext
                   .getBean("customerPaymentRequestProcessor");
           customerPaymentRequestProcessor.setStrCustomerId(customerId);
           customerPaymentRequestProcessor.setCustomerPaymentRequestsMap(customerPaymentRequestsMap);
           taskExecutor.execute(customerPaymentRequestProcessor);

       }
       logger.info("endTime::" + System.currentTimeMillis());
       logger.debug("ProcessPendingPayments.processPendingPayments ends");
   }
   ........
   ```

   Following is the code of Runnable class to process records for each customer

   ```
   @Component
   @Scope("prototype")
   public class CustomerPaymentRequestProcessor implements Runnable {

       private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomerPaymentRequestProcessor.class);

       private String strCustomerId;

       private Map<String, List<PaymentRequestEntity>> customerPaymentRequestsMap;

       private final String REQUEST_TYPE_BALANCE = "Balance";

       @Autowired
       private BalanceServiceImpl balanceServiceImpl;

       @Autowired
       PendingPaymentsSequenceProcessor pendingPaymentsSequenceProcessor;

       @Autowired
       CustomerAuditServiceImpl customerAuditServiceImpl;

       public CustomerPaymentRequestProcessor() {

       }

       public CustomerPaymentRequestProcessor(String strCustomerId,
               Map<String, List<PaymentRequestEntity>> customerPaymentRequestsMap) {
           super();
           this.strCustomerId = strCustomerId;
           this.customerPaymentRequestsMap = customerPaymentRequestsMap;
       }

       @Override
       public void run() {
           logger.debug("CustomerPaymentRequestProcessor.run starts");
           List<PaymentRequestEntity> paymentRequests = getCustomerPaymentRequestsMap().get(getStrCustomerId());
           for (PaymentRequestEntity paymentRequest : paymentRequests) {

               CustomerBalanceResponse customerBalanceResponse = processPaymentRequest(paymentRequest);
               if (!customerBalanceResponse.isCustomerHasBalance()
                       && REQUEST_TYPE_BALANCE.equals(paymentRequest.getRequestType())) {
                   break;
               }

           }
           logger.debug("CustomerPaymentRequestProcessor.run ends");
       }
       ....
       ....
       }
   ```